# How to monitor spark-on-yarn's progress by application id?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to monitor spark-on-yarn mission. I've used yarn resource manager rest api to get spark applications' memory and vcores infomation. But how can I get progress infomation?

I've tried use yarn resource manager rest api, but spark-on-yarn's progress was always 10%. And I've also tried spark web ui rest api, but it only show jobs completed, pending and skipped, it can't show all jobs.

Now I want to use api to solve this problem. I found `JavaStatusTracker` and zeppelin's `JobProgressUtil`. But I don't know how to use application id to get progress.

Comment: you should setup apache livy track spark progress via REST.

Comment: Thank you. I will go to try this way. But I expect this will make my system more complex, because I need to maintain an additional system.

Comment: I didn't find any params like stage, task or progress in REST.. Can you remind me again?

Comment: it was documented here
https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.0/running-spark-applications/content/running_an_interactive_session_with_the_livy_api.html